# Having trouble installing CUDA 11.2 on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, cuda

I tried to install CUDA version 11.2 or 11.0 but I failed many times. I have spent a long time.

see this message:

```
dpkg: error processing package cuda (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
nvidia-dkms-460
cuda-drivers-460
cuda-drivers
cuda-runtime-11-2
nvidia-driver-460
cuda-11-2
cuda-demo-suite-11-2
cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@harishmasand/installing-tensorflow-with-gpu-cuda-and-cudnn-in-ubuntu-20-04-ab2208c06c4a) person, everything was ok until used this command:

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

More details about the system:

```
~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E82sv0000103Csd00008552bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080]
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-520-open - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-520 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Also:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: If you run the command without the -y you can see any messages.

Comment: @David I got the same messages.